# a couple of Makefile issues

Tags: c++, makefile

I've got this Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
CC = g++
EXEC = main
SOURCES = main.cpp listpath.cpp Parser.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES: .cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = tp

DIR_SRC = /src/
DIR_OBJ = /obj/

all: $(SOURCES) $(OBJECTS)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Note this:

- I'm in the directory "." which contains the makefile
- The folder "./src" EXISTS, and has all the .h and .cpp files
- The folder "./obj" doesn't exist, I want makefile to create it and put all the .o there

The error I get is:

```
No rules to build "main.cpp", necessary for "all". Stopping.
```

Help!

Comment: You define `DIR_SRC`, and you never mention it again, so Make doesn't know to look there. Is that enough, or would more advice be helpful?

Comment: OK so I modified this: all: $(DIR_SRC)$(SOURCES) $(OBJECTS), still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you need to investigate VPATH?

Comment: It'd really help if you could just tell me what is wrong with my Makefile :(

Answer (score 1):

All right, from the top:

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
CC = g++
# EXEC = main never used, not needed
SOURCES = main.cpp listpath.cpp Parser.cpp
```

So far, so good. Note that this `SOURCES` doesn't mention `DIR_SRC`, so we'll have to make that connection later (and `$(DIR_SRC)$(SOURCES)` won't work, because the path must be appended to *each member* of the list). But `OBJECTS` really needs paths (e.g. `/obj/main.o`):

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(DIR_OBJ)%.o, $(SOURCES))
EXECUTABLE = tp

DIR_SRC = /src/
DIR_OBJ = /obj/
```

(Personally I don't like putting the trailing slash in the variable, but it's a matter of taste.) The first target is the default target, so it should build what you actually want built:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Don't worry about listing the sources as prerequisites; they will sort themselves out later.

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@  # <-- note the automatic variable $^
```

The `.cpp.o` convention doesn't really work here; we'll have to spell it out. And we must tell Make to search `$(DIR_SRC)` for `.cpp` files:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(DIR_OBJ)%.o: %.cpp $(DIR_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(DIR_OBJ):
    mkdir $@

vpath %.cpp $(DIR_SRC)
```

And tell Make that `clean` is not a real target, just to be safe:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

**EDIT:**

I shouldn't have attempted so much in one step. Let's try something simpler:

```
$(DIR_OBJ)%.o: $(DIR_SRC)%.cpp $(DIR_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I edited my Makefile with your suggestions... now it says "no rule to build target "/obj/main.o", necessary for "tp""

Comment: @l19: sorry, mispasted the `$(OBJECTS)` rule. Fixed. Try it now.

Comment: still won't work :( "no rule to build target "main.cpp", necessary for "/obj/main.o""

Comment: @l19: Wait... Which version of Make are you using? (`make -v`)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `SOURCES` to include the source directory (e.g. `src/main.cpp` etc.).

For the object files, consider something like this:

```
OBJECTS = $(subst src/,obj/,$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o))

# ...

all: $(SOURCES) build

.PHONY: build
build: pre_build $(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: pre_build
pre_build: obj

obj:
    -mkdir obj

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```